# Кастомизированный вид метки в yandex map + react.js

Tags: reactjs, yandex-maps-api

Возникла проблема с кастомизированным видом метки на карте. Вроде создаю метки, получаю их по ajax, в `options` меток добавляю `iconLayout: 'default#imageWithContent`', но он просто не хочет отображаться. Попробовал различные модификации, включаяя `iconLayout: 'default#image`, тут все работает нормально, вместо меток отображаются картинки, но мне необхоимо вместо меток делать `div` с текстом.

```
    import React from 'react';
import { YMaps, Map, Clusterer, Placemark } from 'react-yandex-maps';
import '../css/MapApp.css';
import SideBar from "../SideBar/SideBar";
import {someFunction} from "../../actions";
import ReactDOMServer from "react-dom/server";
import '../css/MapPoints.css'

const carTypes = {
    light: 0,
    truck: 1,
    bus: 2,
    spec: 3
};

let divisions = [];

class MapApp extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            template: null
        };

        this.createTemplateLayoutFactory = ymaps => {
            if (ymaps && !this.state.template) {
                this.setState({
                    template: ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
                        '<div class="bb">' +
                        '<span class="bb-num-org">'+
                        '</span>xzcxzcddfaa<span class="bb-name">' +
                            '</span></div>'
            ),
                });
            }
        };
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <div className="app">
                <SideBar />
                <YMaps
                    query={{
                        apikey: '27544797-3131-4759-9f4b-54f17c827eb2&lang=ru_RU',
                    }}
                    version={"2.1"}
                    >
                    <div className="app-map">
                        <Map
                            onLoad={this.createTemplateLayoutFactory}
                            width={"100%"}
                            height={"100vh"}
                            defaultState={{
                                center: [55.751574, 37.573856],
                                zoom: 5,
                                behaviors: ['default', 'scrollZoom'],
                                controls: [],
                            }}
                            modules={['templateLayoutFactory']}
                        >
                            {console.log('---state  ',this.state.template)}

                            {
                                this.props.points.divisions.map(point => {
                                    return (
                                    <Placemark
                                        key={point.organization.id}
                                        geometry={[point.organization.x_pos, point.organization.y_pos]}
                                        properties={{
                                            hintContent: "asd",
                                            balloonContent: 'Это красивая метка',
                                            iconCaption : 'asd'
                                        }}
                                        modules={[
                                            "geoObject.addon.hint"
                                        ]}

                                        options={{
                                            iconLayout:'default#imageWithContent',

                                            iconContentLayout: this.state.template,
                                            iconContentSize: [100,100],
                                            iconContentOffset: [10, 10],
                                        }}

                                    />)


                                })
                            }
                        </Map>
                    </div>
                </YMaps>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо добавить в модуль карты `layout.ImageWithContent`.

```
   ...
        <Map 
            onLoad={this.createTemplateLayoutFactory}
            defaultState={mapState}
            width="100%"
            height="70vh"
            modules={["templateLayoutFactory", "layout.ImageWithContent"]}
          >
    ...
```